# Cannot retrieve the IScriptFactory object from the ServiceCache.ScriptFactory property

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, add-in, ssms

I am stuck on this simple thing. I have read tons of articles to get the current connection info for an SSMS addin. They all start with this:

```
IScriptFactory scriptFactory = ServiceCache.ScriptFactory;
```

The problem is that I get a **NullReferenceException** when I access this property:

```
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ServiceCache.get_ScriptFactory()
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why. I'm using SSMS 2012, here is the relevant info:

```
+-----------------------------------------+------------------+
| Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  | 11.0.2100.60     |
| Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) | 6.1.7601.17514   |
| Microsoft MSXML                         | 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0  |
| Microsoft Internet Explorer             | 9.11.9600.17239  |
| Microsoft .NET Framework                | 4.0.30319.18063  |
| Operating System                        | 6.1.7601         |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------+
```

Project references:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.RegSvrEnum.dll (Version: 11.0.0.0)
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbench.Interfaces.dll (Version: 11.0.0.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you reference in your project

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlPackageBase.dll

?

Comment: What about SQL Server 2008?
I cannot find this assembly in SqlServer 2008.